# P2P loans dataset WITH lender information

Tags: data-request, finance

Many P2P loan datasets are public. Commonly these datasets include information on the loan and the borrower (e.g. http://kivatools.com/downloads).

However, I am interested in lenders and their activity on the platforms.

Surprisingly, I did not find any dataset that includes (anonymized) information on the lenders of a loan. Meaning (1) which lender did (2) when (3) how much money. I would need this over multiple years (> 5 years).

Has anyone a link to such a dataset with time-series information on lenders and their activity?

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to web scrape it yourself and are OK with crowdfunding instead of crowdlending, [Funderbeam](https://www.funderbeam.com/) has the list of investors next to the campaign (screenshot attached). Some are anonymous but for some you get their actual name or company name, so can get additional financial data from public sources. The platform Funderbeam goes back about 10 years and the old campaigns are available when clicking on the startup name > Company > Campaign. You may have to become a member of Funderbeam to access this data, but membership is free. [image: Funderbeam campaign with investor list]